# Python: safely using the same serial port with multiple processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyserial

How do I go about safely accessing a serial port with multiple Python processes? One process should be able to freely write or read to the serial port without fear of corruption/error due to the other process.

For example:

- Process A writes to the serial port
- At the same time, Process B writes to the serial port and then reads from the serial port after

Would using multiprocessing queues be the best way to handle this?

Anyone able to provide an example on how to do this?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "freely write or read to the serial port without fear of corruption/error due to the other process." If your goal is to ensure that only one process can access the port at a time and will not allow any other process to access it until it is willing to release its ownership of the port, then use a `mulitprocessing.Lock` to serialize access.

Comment: An example of what I mean would be: Process A writes to the serial port, then at the same time Process B writes and then reads from the serial port, and also at the same time Process C reads from the serial port.

Comment: How could two processes read simultaneously from the same serial port and expect to receive a meaningful, complete message unless each message was only a single byte long *and* it doesn't matter which process reads each message?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was wondering if there was a good way to ensure each process can be queued in a manner that would allow each process to read the message it was requesting, for example. 

Would using locks be a good way of doing this?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do. You need to describe your problem more fully. Locks ensure serial access to a resource plain and simple. But it's not clear how messages are sent and how responses to that message are subsequently received. If you just want to send a message and wait for a response and ensure no other process can use the port until that send/receive sequence occurs, then use a lock.  (more...)

Comment: You could also tag a message with a process number such as 1, 2 or 3 and have a response also tagged with the same number. The processes then write the messages to a single queue that a process reads and does all the sending and receiving. When it gets a response, it writes it to one of 3 response queues provided by the three senders.